# julia metaprogramming and nloops variable evaluation

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

I am a noob at metaprogramming so maybe I am not understanding this. I thought the purpose of the `@nloops` macro in `Base.Cartesian` was to make it possible to code an arbitrary number of nested for loops, in circumstances where the dimension is unknown a priori. In the documentation for the module, the following example is given:

```
@nloops 3 i A begin
    s += @nref 3 A i
end
```

which evaluates to

```
for i_3 = 1:size(A,3)
    for i_2 = 1:size(A,2)
        for i_1 = 1:size(A,1)
            s += A[i_1,i_2,i_3]
        end
    end
end
```

Here, the number 3 is known a priori. For my purposes, however, and for the purposes that I thought nloops was created, the number of nested levels is not known ahead of time. So I would not be able to hard code the integer 3. Even in the documentation, it is stated:

> The (basic) syntax of @nloops is as follows:
>
> - The first argument must be an integer (not a variable) specifying the number of loops.
>
> ...

If I assign an integer value - say the dimension of an array that is passed to a function - to some variable, the nloops macro no longer works:

```
b = 3
@nloops b i A begin
    s += @nref b A i
end
```

This returns an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching _nloops(::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::Expr)
Closest candidates are:
  _nloops(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::Expr...) at cartesian.jl:43
...
```

I don't know how to have nloops evaluate the `b` variable as an integer rather than a symbol. I have looked at the documentation and tried various iterations of `eval` and other functions and macros but it is either interpreted as a symbol or an `Expr`. What is the correct, julian way to write this?

Answer (score 3):

See [supplying the number of expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/devdocs/cartesian/#Supplying-the-number-of-expressions-1):

```
julia> A = rand(4, 4, 3)  # 3D array (Array{Int, 3})
```

A generated function is kinda like a macro, in that the resulting expression is not returned, but compiled and executed on invocation/call, it also *sees* the **type** (and their type parameters of course) of the arguments, ie:

- inside the generated function, `A` is `Array{T, N}`, **not** the value of the array.
- so `T` is `Int` and `N` is `3`!

Here inside the quoted expression, `N` is interpolated into the expression, with the syntax `$N`, which evaluates to `3`:

```
julia> @generated function mysum(A::Array{T,N}) where {T,N}
           quote
               s = zero(T)
               @nloops $N i A begin
                   s += @nref $N A i
               end
               s
           end
       end
mysum (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mysum(A)
23.2791638775186
```

You could construct the expression and then evaluate it, ie.:

```
julia> s = 0; n = 3;

julia> _3loops = quote
           @nloops $n i A begin
               global s += @nref $n A i
           end
       end
quote
    @nloops 3 i A begin
        global s += @nref(3, A, i)
    end
end

julia> eval(_3loops)

julia> s
23.2791638775186
```

I have scrubbed manually the `LineNumberNode`s from the AST for readability (there is also `MacroTools.prettify`, that does it for you).

Running this example in the REPL **needs** to declare `s` as **`global`** inside the loop in Julia 1.0.